# Using the initialize function in Backbone Router

Tags: node.js, backbone.js, backbone-routing, backbone.js-collections

I'm in the midst of creating my first backbone app using Node/express and Mongodb. The app is an online food menu and ordering system that collects all the data from mongo on the first page load and pushes it into a Backbone collection. I'm using the initialize function in the Backbone Router to fetch() the data and put it into a collection. My problem is that the index Router is loading before the Initialize function has finished. I have confirmed that the initialize function runs correctly because I can access the collection in the browser console.

I may be going about this the wrong way but here is a simplified version of my router:

```
GDB.Router = Backbone.Router.extend ({
    routes: {
        '': 'index',
        'drinks': 'drinks'
    },

    meals: {},

    initialize: function() {
        meals = new GDB.Collections.Meals
        meals.fetch();
    }, 

    index: function() {
            var mealsView = new GDB.Views.Meals ({collection: meals});
            $('#GDBContainer').append(mealsView.render().el);           
    },

    drinks: function() {
            var drinksView = new GDB.Views.Meals ({collection: meals.byCategory('drinks')});
            $('#GDBContainer').append(drinksView.render().el);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Most likely, the `initialize` function *has* finished before the `index` function is called, but your `fetch` is asynchronous so the collection is not finished loading when you try to render your `mealsView`.

```
GDB.Router = Backbone.Router.extend ({
    routes: {
        '': 'index',
        'drinks': 'drinks'
    },

    initialize: function() {
        this.meals = new GDB.Collections.Meals
        // fetch returns a jquery promise
        this.fetchingMeals = this.meals.fetch();
    }, 

    index: function() {
            var self = this;
            // maybe show loading spinner here
            $('#GDBContainer').html('<div>Loading</div>');

            this.fetchingMeals.done(function(){
                // now this.meals is done fetching!
                var mealsView = new GDB.Views.Meals ({collection: self.meals});
                $('#GDBContainer').html(mealsView.render().el);  
            });         
    },

    drinks: function() {
            var self = this;
            // maybe show loading spinner here
            $('#GDBContainer').html('<div>Loading</div>');

            this.fetchingMeals.done(function(){
                var drinksView = new GDB.Views.Meals ({collection: self.meals.byCategory('drinks')});
                $('#GDBContainer').html(drinksView.render().el);
            });
    }
});
```

Comment: I had a similar solution to this but I put the fetch method inside each of the router methods. The problem there is that an ajax request is made and the collection is repopulated every time you change routes which defeats the purpose of the collection when I already have everything I need inside of it. I was hoping that Backbone would delay the start of any Router method until the initialize method and anything inside of it had finished executing. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Paul's solution, or listen to collection's add/reset/whatever events in the view.

```
view.listenTo(model, 'reset', view.render);
```